# Unity Editor windows went black

Tags: graphics, unity, bug

I recently bought a new laptop, with Intel i5-5200U HD graphics 5500 and AMD Radeon R5 M230 2GB and 8gb ram, and heres what happens with my Unity: If open it, minimize it and then maximize again, it'll render some weird black screen in random areas of the editor, like this:

[image]

[image]

But, if I instead of minimizing unity and just opened other window , when I go back to unity nothing happens, no black weird "squares". So this just happens when I minimize unity itself and then maximize it, if I maximize another program over unity and then open unity again, it will not happen. Can anyone please tell me why this happens??? I always have to restart unity.... Is this a problem with my video card? plz help

Comment: if you're running windows try updating your video card drivers

Comment: but its already updated...

Comment: You have dual graphics, I'm not currently aware of how AMD implement this but you should try setting it so that Unity only uses the 'high performance' graphics. There's probably a driver utility to let you do this. Essentially, try forcing Unity not to use the Intel graphics. I've had a few problems with the editor having graphical glitches and corruption and forcing use of a dedicated GPU normally clears them up.

Comment: Idk how to do that, i tried disable intel graphics but it didnt work, i tried run unity from amd control panel but it didnt worked too, idk what to do, and its just with unity

Comment: This looks like an engine bug you should contact Unity support about.

Answer (score 1):

If you have dual graphics: force Unity not to use integrated graphics, and then restart Unity.

I switched from Intel integrated graphics to nVidia graphics for Unity in

```
NVIDIA Control Panel 
  -> Manage 3D Settings
    -> Program Settings
      -> Unity
        -> High-performance NVIDIA processor
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks! but a dude on unity support helped me, i just switched the render from DX11 to DX9 and everything is cool now, he said it was a known bug, so, yea, thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

[According to this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/blank-game-view.421817/), an issue similar to this is known and a fix is in the works.

As a temporary workaround, users report that running Unity with the command line flag:

```
-force-gfx-direct
```

will force the editor to run single-threaded and stop the issue from occurring.

You can add this flag to the shortcut you use to run Unity. Let me know if you need instructions how.